# PLESK in Windows Server 2019 Standard - local user limitation

Tags: windows-server-2019, plesk

I recently installed PLESK in Windows Server 2019 Essentials, without enabling or joining in Active Directory. There are 20 domains that I support for IIS, FTP and DNS services. Regarding the e-mail service, I use an external software. Unfortunately, this license has a limitation of 25 local user accounts and PLESK has created 68 local account until now.
I contact with PLESK and they told me to upgrade to Windows Server 2019 Standard edition (WS2019S).

Looking in the internet I didn't find answers for the questions below.

1. How many local users does the WS2019S edition supports?
2. There is something called user or device CAL and RDS CAL. Do I need user CAL in order the PLESK to run or just the license for WS2019S is fine for my scenario?
3. Looking in ebay for WS2019S license I found some sellers who have very low price and I wonder if it is reliable?

Comment: Hi, Software licencing queston are offtopic, but in the Windows world, usually each user that log in to the server, via a service or remote, need a user cal, specially if the credential is checked on the server (workgroup or domain). The only time it's not enforced is if you do a web site in exemple and the anonymous traffic coming to the server.

Answer (score 1):

> How many local users does the WS2019S edition supports?

I am not aware of any limit. Obviously there are technical requirements (RAM etc.), but I am not aware of any lowish (below 10k) limit that is (like in Essential) enforced by some mechanism.

2: That depends on the service. THAT SAID: You need a CAL when people actually use a service that uses a CAL. IIS anonymous: no. FTP uploads - that is named user. RDS is not needed at all - those are Remote Desktop Licenses and I would be hard pressed to assume a plesk base web host does Remote Desktop (note: admin access is NOT licensed with this).

3: How the heck should we rate on that? Because we can not judge - and do not want to judge - a server. There are a LOT of illegally copied licenses out there. THAT SAID: If you BUY one, there is IIRC a program at MS - you send in the invoice and get a legal license (and they go for the seller). The important thing is that YOU can proove that you deald in good faith and have proper paperwork. I Would be careful with super low prices - MS Is not givine the licenses away, so where do they come from?